# Git - some files are marked as changed but 'git diff' doesn't show anything

Tags: git

I am quite new to Git, thus maybe I am missing something here.

```
dan@one:/var/www/$ git status -s
M  GoogleChromeExtension.js
M  ApiClient.js
```

So clearly 2 files have been changed.
But when I run:

```
git diff
```

no output is shown. I was expecting to get the changes between my working copy and the latest commit.

I am sure yesterday everything was working as expecting...

Is it maybe because I haven't been pushing the changes to the remote server?

P.S.: I am using GitHub

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Please add the output of "git status" without the "-s"

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem - even though only couple of lines have been changed, the whole file shows up in the git diff. Feels like it's an IDE issue (using Intelli J). Any pointers?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Do a `git diff --cached` - it compares the HEAD and index, ie stuff added for commit.

Just a `git diff` is between index and working directory, so if all the changes have been staged for commit, you won' see anything in `git diff`

The third form is `git diff <commit>` which compares working directory and commit. So doing `git diff HEAD` will also give you the diff that you want as well.

Comment: Also, notice that you can tell from the output of git-status that the file modifications are in the index because the 'M' appears in the first column.  Had the changes not been staged, the 'M' would be in the second column.

Comment: @William Pursell - good point. Also, if color output is enabled, former has green color M and the latter a red. At least, that is the case for me in git bash on Windows. So it is not exactly necessary to just have `git status` but `git status -s` can also be pretty informative if you know where to look.

Comment: `git status -s` is largely meant for machine consumption; computers are usually better than us at noticing which column the M is in. (And we're better at reading colors.)

Comment: @Jefromi - I hear you, but for someone experienced in git, `git status -s` might be very useful.

Comment: True - it's definitely quite usable, especially with colors, but I'd say the majority of people asking and reading questions like this one are probably at the point where they're better off with a little more context.

Comment: The case you describe might be the most frequent but just to let you know: I had the situation that neither `git diff` nor `git diff --cached` showed any changes, yet one file was listed as unstaged change. After double checking that there were no changes I did a `git checkout <filename>` to get rid of the spurious change.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on exactly what is going on, there may be two solutions to this.  It would be best if you didn't use short mode since it hides information important for debugging this.

If you expect changes, try running `git diff HEAD` to compare the working directory to the last commit.  If you have already `git add`ed the changes, the default git diff action will be to not show those differences.  See the http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff man page DESCRIPTION which talks about this.  The `git status` output (without -s) would help everyone see whether this was the case.

Alternately, if you didn't expect changes, this could be an OS/filesystem problem.  Please report your OS and filesystem information.

Answer (score 4):

> use --no-pager flag with diff

```
git --no-pager diff filepath/filename.extn
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're not actually within another git repository.
And if for some reason above commands fails, try to run:

```
git show HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had this problem, and found it happened because I changed my .gitattributes file for the repository.  Have you changed any of your .gitattributes files recently?  Are all the files that are changed of the same type?  My recent issues affected *.sql files, for example.  When I undid the change to .gitattributes, the source files became unchanged again.

Answer (score 0):

git diff doesn't show the difference between last two commits.
git diff shows difference between last commit and the changes you have done to your code.